# Sybase heavy Disk I/O issue

Tags: windows-server-2003, database, sql, database-performance, sybase

I have a Sybase 15 server that is constantly reading from the hard disk. I noticed that the sqlsrvr.exe is the culprit which is the main database engine. This is a pretty utilized server that is running a 32 bit instance which means the process can only use 3GB of memory (it is using the full 3GB).

After running the sysinternals process monitor tool it was determined that the service is reading the database data files (\data\instance*.dat files) to the tune of 3,000-4,000 times a minute. Performance monitoring observed that the disk is idle only 15% of the time and has constant I/O.

I am concerned the database has some type of memory management issue or has become over utilized over time.

Is it abnormal for Sybase to run like this? We really aren't having an performance issues\complaints. What are the next steps to investigate typically for an issue like that?

Comment: I'm not sure which version of Sybase 15 you're using, but it is possible that your product is End of Life since march 2015. Similarly, Windows Server 2003 extended support went end of life on july 14th 2015. If you're not having performance problems it would be best not to start poking it with a stick just yet. Perhaps planning an upgrade to newer platforms will give you some more security for the future.

Comment: sp_sysmon is one of the main tools for monitoring performance inside the data server. If you want to poke around, you can find details in the Sybase Performance and Tuning documentation.